# Even when DB has records, while trying to edit records, code does not work

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update records in `'pantry-info'` table. Code goes to the `if` loop instead of `else`

The code is mentioned below, what am I doing wrong?

DB connection is:

```
require 'config/connectDB.php';
session_start();
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM temp WHERE'.  " pan_id = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Trying to read DB table values in form as follows:

```
<?php   
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result1) == 0)
            {
                echo '<h2><a href="javascript:delete_user('.$id.')">This record already exists. Do you want to delete it?</a></h2>';
            } else { ?>
                <h4>Edit the record here:</h4>
                <br>
                <form name="pantryinfo" id="pantryForm" method = "post"  action="update.php" data-toggle="validator" role="form">
                    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1,MYSQLI_ASSOC))  {   ?>
                        <div class="control-group form-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="panid" name="panid" value="<?php echo $row['pan_id'];?>">
                                <p class="help-block"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group form-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <label>Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['pname'];?>" required>
                                <p class="help-block"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </form>
           <?php
            }
            }
        ?>
```

Similar code works fine on a different page retrieving values from another DB table. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$result1` you sure you didn't mean `$result`? I don't see a query for `$result1`. I only see `$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);` same for the other variable used.

Comment: and if so, this qualifies as an undefined index/variable close dupe

Comment: `$result1` was a typo from my side. Its just `result` everywhere. The code runs the logic for `if` condition instead of going into `else`

Comment: I also don't see any query to update a db.

Comment: I will doing an update on another page. I have a redirection in the form to `update-pantry.php`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. In the SQL query I used `$result` as a variable and in the `if-else` code I was using `result1`.

Thank you Fred for pointing it out.

Comment: *"$result1 was a typo from my side. Its just `result` everywhere. The code runs the logic for if condition instead of going into else"* - but you said...otherwise.